# Rows affected by different updates/inserts in same statement

Tags: java, sql

I need help getting the number of rows affected by a series of update statements in the same preparedStatement.

```
String sql = "update TABLE1 ....; "
            +"update TABLE2 ....; "
            +"update TABLE3 ....; "
            +"insert into TABLE4....; "

PreparedStatement pstmt = BD.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1,x);
.....
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

it works, the updates and inserts are successful, but i cant check the rows affected.

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: int n = pstmt.executeStatement()

Comment: @Serg SQLServer 2008

Comment: @dsp_user it seems pstmt does not have this method. Only executeUpdate, executeQuery, executeBatch

Comment: Sorry, I meant int n = .pstmt.executeUpdate (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

Comment: @dsp_user it returns the affected rows of the last DML. In my example above it would return the affected row of the Insert DML only. I need to know the affected rows of every DML

Comment: If you want to retrieve the affected rows for each update (or insert) statement, then you should use batch updates (I'll provide a simple example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get affected rows for each of your statements, you should either a) execute your statements one at a time b )use batch updates. I'm using the latter because it's more efficient (also I'm using a Statement but you might use a PreparedStatement instead (you will have to cast it to Statement though)

```
    public int[] executeBatchUpdate(List<String> sqlStatements) throws EasyORMException{


    int[] batchResults=null;

    Statement stmt=null; 

    for (int i=0; i<sqlStatements.size();i++){

    try{

   if(stmt==null)    
     stmt = conn.createStatement();

    stmt.addBatch(sqlStatements.get(i));

    }catch(SQLException sqle){     
      //log or throw exception  
    }    
    }//end for loop 

    try {

     batchResults = stmt.executeBatch();

    }catch (SQLException sqle) {

      //log or throw exception

     }    

}

   return batchResults;

}
```

The method above returns an array of int values (for each of your statements). Note that batch updates are JDBC/DB driver dependent so, in case of an exception, you may see different behaviour for different database systems (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) .

Comment: Then, why don't you accept the answer so other people can benefit from it?

Comment: sorry, my bad. Thanks again